# Universalized array is not perfectly acting as an array

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I am working on some permission module and for this I maid all **data** as a **serialized array**. When I'm trying to display it back using **unserialized, inner arrays** are showing as `null`. I think it is not taking it as an exact array. Please help me with some solutions.

This is the code am using

```
$serialisedString = 'a:3:{i:1;a:2:{s:14:&quot;&#39;permissionId&#39;&quot;;s:1:&quot;1&quot;;s:13:&quot;&#39;permissions&#39;&quot;;a:3:{s:6:&quot;&#39;view&#39;&quot;;s:1:&quot;1&quot;;s:6:&quot;&#39;edit&#39;&quot;;s:1:&quot;1&quot;;s:8:&quot;&#39;delete&#39;&quot;;s:1:&quot;0&quot;;}}i:2;a:2:{s:14:&quot;&#39;permissionId&#39;&quot;;s:1:&quot;2&quot;;s:13:&quot;&#39;permissions&#39;&quot;;a:3:{s:6:&quot;&#39;view&#39;&quot;;s:1:&quot;1&quot;;s:6:&quot;&#39;edit&#39;&quot;;s:1:&quot;1&quot;;s:8:&quot;&#39;delete&#39;&quot;;s:1:&quot;0&quot;;}}i:3;a:2:{s:14:&quot;&#39;permissionId&#39;&quot;;s:1:&quot;3&quot;;s:13:&quot;&#39;permissions&#39;&quot;;a:3:{s:6:&quot;&#39;view&#39;&quot;;s:1:&quot;1&quot;;s:6:&quot;&#39;edit&#39;&quot;;s:1:&quot;1&quot;;s:8:&quot;&#39;delete&#39;&quot;;s:1:&quot;0&quot;;}}}';
$serialiceData  =   html_entity_decode($serialisedString);
$serialiceData  =   str_replace('&#39;',"'",$serialiceData);
$permissionArray =   unserialize($serialiceData);
```

Till this is its is seeing OK, and I can select the first arrays like this

```
print_r($permissionArray[1]);
```

But when I'm trying take one inner value, it showing as null

```
print_r($permissionArray[1]['permissions']);
```

Please anyone tell what is the problem and also give me one solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem,
we have to give the key as string so we have to include the single quotes also as key. This single quote is coming when I serialize one array of post. I got the answer by calling like this

```
print_r($permissionArray[1]["'permissions'"]);
```

I am not sure that it is a perfect method. Please add the answer if anyone have another solution

Answer (score 0):

There is just a problem with you key on the second print_r-call.

The $permissionsArray's first field (index zero) is the field with the key "permissionID". 
The $permissionsArray's second field (index one) is the field with the key "permissions".

So what you are doing here is calling $permissionArray["permissions"]["permissions"]. Because this field doens't exists you get the value of null. :)

So the three possible inner values of your array are "view", "edit", "delete".

```
print_r($permissionArray[1]['view']);
print_r($permissionArray[1]['edit']);
print_r($permissionArray[1]['delete']);
```

or

```
print_r($permissionArray['permissions']['view']);
print_r($permissionArray['permissions']['edit']);
print_r($permissionArray['permissions']['delete']);
```

Comment: That also not working., and I found the problem and solution. But I am not sure that it is perfect